# c++ get list of hdf5 attributes

Tags: c++, attributes, hdf5

Can someone help me with the C++ HDF5 API and it's attributes? I want to read data from an HDF5 file without knowing all attributes available. So I try to find a solution to get a list of available attributes but it seems that this is not a usual problem. I neither found a solution online nor am I able to solve the problem using the API. But I'am quite sure that it must be possible and would be very happy if someone is out there knowing how to do this and sharing the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use

```
ssize_t H5Aget_name_by_idx( hid_t loc_id, const char *obj_name, H5_index_t idx_type, H5_iter_order_t order, hsize_t n, char *name, size_t size, hid_t lapl_id )
```

or

```
herr_t H5Aget_info_by_idx( hid_t loc_id, const char *obj_name, H5_index_t idx_type, H5_iter_order_t order, hsize_t n, H5A_info_t *ainfo, hid_t lapl_id )
```

I assume the attributes indices are numerical, so you can try until *herr_t* becomes negative (then there is an error). In the first case the values 0 and NULL can be passed in for the parameters size and name. The function’s return value will provide the correct value for size.